# Error messages when using CS50 IDE for first time for Problem Set 2 - Readability

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ide, cs50

I am brand new to programming and making my way through the CS50 online course.

In lecture 2, David introduced CS50 IDE, which I am now using for the first time for Problem Set 2 - Readability. However, I am encountering some error messages when I try to run a simple "hello, world" program.

Here are the steps I am taking in order:

1. Open CS50 IDE
2. Sign in with my GitHub login
3. Execute `cd` to make sure I am in home directory
4. Execute `mkdir hello` to create a new directory in my home folder
5. Execute `cd hello` to navigate to the new directory
6. Execute `open hello.c` to create new file in the new directory

At this point everything looks familiar to me, so I test it with the simple "hello, world" program:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

I then run `make hello` and receive the below error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'hello'. Stop.
```

I then noticed that even though I previously ran open hello.c there actually isn't a hello.c file in the hello directory on the left. So I manually right clicked the hello directory and selected New File and created hello.c and tried to run it again. I then get the below error message:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    hello.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o hello
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<builtin>: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I've googled around a few different responses to similar questions, but can't seem to solve the issue. I'm pretty confused, so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm also attaching a few screenshots of my window if helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may find folks more familiar with the CS50 tools here: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the second screen shot, the useful information may have scrolled of the top of the window.  Perhaps make it bigger?  Os since it is just text post it directly.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that I was not saving the file into the directory before compiling. I tried to mark as solved, but it says I need to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer (???).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not saving the file before compiling. Marking as solved!

Answer (score 0):

In the CS50 IDE it seems to work best if you set up a new file in the file menu ("create file")and name it before you begin writing your program. I had the same problem at first. It doesn't seem to know your file is there or perhaps more accurately, recognise it fully, unless you do this first. In other words CS50 IDE doesn't seem confident the file name or file exists unless you create it first of all from the file menu, in the correct directory. I don't know how this works on other compilers, but I imagine its done like this to help form the thinking pattern of "C does not know X unless I declare X first"). glad you fixed it!